# How to use powershell to copy files off of root of drive to another folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have set up a powershell script to listen for when I insert an SD card in my laptop, and then copy all the files off this SD card to a folder on my internal drive. I have it all set up to listen for the SD card to be connected, and this part works perfectly. I also have set up:

```
Copy-Item E:\DCIM\ -Destination C:\Users\FRHD\Desktop\auto_offload\ -Recurse
```

to copy all the contents of a folder into a folder on my desktop. It works, but I am having trouble when I want to copy from the Root of a drive. I use the following code:

```
Copy-Item E:\ -Destination C:\Users\FRHD\Desktop\auto_offload\ -Recurse
```

but powershell has trouble with E:\ (I'm afraid it doesn't see it as a proper folder.) I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need to use `E:\*` instead of just ```E:\```.

Comment: Great! Now is there any way to display progress or a success message for the progress of the copy?

Comment: If it's automated, as in listening for the SD insertion. You could try a simple UI popup. https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/06/09/display-gui-message-boxes-in-powershell.aspx?m=1 is the first link I found. Otherwise you could just add a quoted saying to the end of the script. "file transfer complete"